# Fortran: Variables changing on their own

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I'm having a problem of variables getting over-written for I don't know what reason. I've posted a chunk of the code below so you can see how things are declared. The variables strain,Qi,Qf,Qd,tel and Gc are passed into the subroutine and used to calculate ssgrad,strn0,strss0.

My problem is that tel and Gc are passed into the subroutine OK but are for some reason change value during this chunk of code.

Using print statements I've found that the problem first occurs during the 2nd do loop. When I set strss0 to 0, Gc and tel change value from both being equal to 1, to seemingly random numbers: tel=11.52822 Gc=-8.789086 (Just shown for the sake of example)

Each time I run the code they are set to the same values though.

Just to let you know, this subroutine interfaces with a commercial finite element package.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this

```
subroutine initcalcs(strain,Qi,Qf,Qd,tel,Gc,ssgrad,strn0,strss0)

  implicit none

  integer :: i,j

  real*8:: nstrn0,nstrs0,strn0,strnf,varsq,normvar,lmbda0,lmbdaf,
 # ssgrad,t0,tt,tel,nstrnf,nstrsf,Gc

  real*8, dimension(3) :: strain,stran0,stranf,strss0,strssf,var

  real*8, dimension(3,3) :: Qd,Qi,Qf


  lmbda0=1.0d0                                                                                          


  nstrn0=0.0d0                                                                             
  do i=1,3
        stran0(i)=0.0d0
        stran0(i)=strain(i)*lmbda0                                                         
        nstrn0=nstrn0+stran0(i)**2                                                         
  end do                                                                                    

  nstrn0=dsqrt(nstrn0)                                                                     


  do i=1,3
        strss0(i)=0.0d0 
  end do
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring them as `intent(in)` variables?

Answer (score 4):

In Fortran, there are two common causes of the corruption of memory values.  One is a subscript error, where you assign to an array element using an incorrect subscript value.  This writes to a memory location outside of the array.  The other is a disagreement between the arguments in the call to a procedure (subroutine or function) and the dummy arguments of the procedure.  Either can cause problems to appear at source code locations different from the actual cause.  Suggestions: inspect your code for these problems.  Turn on stringent warning and error checking options of your compiler.  The use of Fortran >=90 and modules gives Fortran much better ability to automatically find argument consistency problems.  You could monitor the memory locations with a debugger and see what it modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with M. S. B.: turn on stringent warnings and error checking and verify the subroutine calls are passing arguments that have the same type and shape (array dimensions) as the subroutine expects.

The colons in the variable declaration syntax imply this is Fortran90 or later. If that's the case, I strongly suggest using the `INTENT` modifier to specify whether arguments are intended to be read-only.

For example, let's assume that of the arguments passed to this routine, `strain`, `Qi`, `Qf`, `Qd`, `tel`, and `Gc` are read-only input and the arguments are `ssgrad`, `strn0`, and `strss0` are returned as output; that is, whatever value they have is overwritten by this routine.

The variable declarations for the arguments would change to:

```
real*8, dimension(3), intent(in) :: strain
real*8, dimension(3,3), intent(in) :: Qi, Qf, Qd
real*8, intent(in) :: tel, Gc

real*8, intent(out) :: strn0, ssgrad 
real*8, dimension(3), intent(out) :: strss0
```

The `INTENT` keyword is an addition to Fortran 90 which allows the user to specify which arguments are read-only (`INTENT(IN)`), initialized but which may be modified within the routine (`INTENT(INOUT)`) and which are treated as uninitialized and will be set within the routine (`INTENT(OUT)`).

If `INTENT` is not specified, it is defaults to `INOUT` which is consistent with FORTRAN 77 (Note that there are minor differences between `INTENT(INOUT)` and `INTENT` not being specified but they aren't relevant in this example).

A good compiler will throw an error if a routine tries to assign a value to a variable declared `INTENT(IN)` and will at least throw a warning if a variable declared `INTENT(OUT)` doesn't get assigned a value.

If possible, set `INTENT(IN)` on all the variables which are supposed to be read-only. This may not be possible, depending on how those variables are passed to other routines. If `INTENT` isn't specified on arguments to routines called within this routine, it will default to `INOUT`. If you pass an `INTENT(IN)` variable as an `INTENT(INOUT)` argument, the compiler will throw an error. If this is happening in code you control, you have have to specify `INTENT` in a number of routines. This may or may not be desirable depending on whether you want to generally improve your code or just fix this one problem really quickly.

I'm assuming some of these variables are passed to external routines in the finite element package which I 'm guessing is linked to your code rather than compiled; I'm not sure how compile-time intent checking is handled in that case.